# jQuery UI Slider conflicts with Mootools.fx slide

Tags: jquery

As it was mentioned in this question [jQuery UI Slider moving upwards and disappearing in the div when used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024102/jquery-ui-slider-moving-upwards-and-disappearing-in-the-div-when-used)
I have exactly the same problem, as a part of Joompla 1.6 i want to include a basic slider inside the back end
I have tried disabling mootools, but is a part of the joomla backend, also i haven't managed ti figure out the answer dostrog posted in the question above
Any more help? I'am using the latest jquery and jqueryui libraries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I replace this part of code in **jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js**

```
(function(d){d.widget("ui.slider",d.ui.mouse,{widgetEventPrefix:"slide"

(function(d){d.widget("ui.slider",d.ui.mouse,{widgetEventPrefix:"slidez"
```

line 418

mootools slide effect is disable

Work with

mootools 1.2.5

jQuery 1.6.2

jQuery UI 1.8.16

Answer (score 9):

here is the ticket at jquery: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4168
The workaround they suggesting is to remove method "slide" from element before initializing slider:

```
jQuery('div.slider').removeAttr('slide').slider({...});
```

That didn't help me, but I found similar solution that work for me:

```
jQuery('div.slider')[0].slide = null;
jQuery('div.slider').slider({...});
```

Comment: This is a much better approach, as it does not requires to hack the ui/mootols library(also, if the library is updated the hack will be gone).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me a lot. With a note that if you have multiple sliders on the same page you would have to iterate the elements instead of removing the slide method from the very first one

Answer (score 4):

jQuery UI is planning on switching to firing "widget:event" (for example "slider.slide") to avoid naming collisions with native events.

In the meantime you can switch the prefix the slider plugin uses as a workaround -  http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/4uXbk/.

Answer (score 1):

removeAttr('slide') is effective with  jQuery 1.5.1 and jQuery UI 1.8.6
on higher version jQuery, enable mootools slideOut effect on slider drag

PS. I use mootools 1.2.5 from Joomla 1.5.23