# How to block global JQuery Effect which causes UI Slider to disappear

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, hide, global

I'm using the following JQuery UI slider script to input values:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                            jQuery( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
                                range: "min",
                                value: 5,
                                min: 1,
                                step: 5,
                                max: 60,
                                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                                    jQuery( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
                                }

                            });
                            jQuery( "#amount" ).val( jQuery( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) );


                    </script>
                    <div style="width:100%;clear:both;margin-top:10px;"></div>
                    <div id="slider-range-min"></div>
```

Whenever the knob on the slid is clicked or slid, it is hidden or slides up out of site.  I have not been able to determine which effect exactly is causing the slider to disappear.  This is a problem, because if a user happens to initially set the wrong value, the cannot correct it  because the slider has disappeared.  Is there a way to block the slider from other globale effects.  Again I am not sure which exact effect is causing this (hide,slideUP,etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a ranged slider in JQueryUI, you need to use `.slider('values')` instead of `.slider('value')`.

Per the docs:

```
value
.slider( "value" , [value] )
Gets or sets the value of the slider. For single handle sliders.

values
.slider( "values" , index , [value] )
Gets or sets the values of the slider. For multiple handle or range sliders.
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly have a MooTools and jQuery library collision ([1](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4168), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024102/jquery-ui-slider-moving-upwards-and-disappearing-in-the-div-when-used))?

One workaround is to remove each MooTools slide method before applying the jQuery UI slider as such:

```
jQuery('div.slider')
.each(function(){
    //removing the MooTools slide method
    this.slide=null;
})
.slider({
    ...
});
```